Constrained template function never gets called
I have two template member functions that should be called based on meeting a constraint (being derived from a specific type)
I have the general case template function called addScheme defined as follows:
template <typename Field>
template <typename Scheme>
void TransportEquation<Field>::addScheme(Scheme&& scheme) {
    if (scheme.needsCorrection()) {
        _n_corrected_schemes++;
    }

    _schemes.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Scheme>(std::forward<Scheme>(scheme)));
}

I added another two functions, for two specific cases.
The first function I have no issues with, the template type Diffusion should be inherited from IDiffusion:
template <typename Field>
template <typename Diffusion>
requires std::derived_from<Diffusion, IDiffusion>
void TransportEquation<Field>::addScheme(Diffusion&& diffusion) {
    if (diffusion.needsCorrection()) {
        _n_corrected_schemes++;
    }

    auto diff_scheme = std::make_shared<Diffusion>(std::forward<Diffusion>(diffusion));
    _diff_scheme = diff_scheme;
    _schemes.emplace_back(diff_scheme);
}

My problem is with the other one, in which the scheme should be derived from IConvection<G> where G is another template type:
template <typename Field>
template <typename Convection, typename G>
requires std::derived_from<Convection, scheme::convection::IConvection<G>>
void TransportEquation<Field>::addScheme(Convection&& convection) {
    if (convection.needsCorrection()) {
        _n_corrected_schemes++;
    }

    auto conv_scheme = std::make_shared<Convection>(std::forward<Convection>(convection));
    _conv_scheme = conv_scheme;
    _schemes.emplace_back(conv_scheme);
}

This function never gets called, and the general one addScheme(Scheme&& scheme) always gets called instead. I don't know what is wrong with the function definition and why the constraint is never met?
In case it's useful, this is how I declare IConvection:
template <typename GradScheme = gradient::LeastSquares>
class IConvection {
// ...
};

and this is a derived type, that never matches the constrain of addScheme(Convection&&) and addScheme(Scheme&&) gets called instead:
template <typename G = gradient::LeastSquares>
class Upwind : public IConvection<G> {}


Provide a [mcve]. Something that can be directly copy/pasted and used to reproduce the said issue/problem.

In particular, it would help if it's a single snippet we can copypaste directly (no missing headers, no multiple files).

In your code G cannot be deduced, so the template cannot be called.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks that was my first guess also, but I don't know to make it possible for the function to deduce the G type.

"is it okay to post a github link to the repo" No, it's your homework to reduce it to a smaller example. It's explained in the link the first comment. Sometimes people will spot the error just with their eyes, but if it's more complicated, the example helps a lot.

It's not possible to deduce G in any form. You can add in the template IConvection a field like the sub-type using Its_a_IConvection = bool; then detect the fact that any IConvection<B> has this special sub-type.

You might use traits is_template_base_of: requires is_template_base_of<scheme::convection::IConvection, Convection>::value.

You can derive IConvection<G> from some kind of non-template (possibly empty) base class IConvectionBase and check derivation from that instead.

You don't have anything specifying G, so it isn't deduced, so the template is never matched.
You could add a type alias to IConvection
template <typename GradScheme = gradient::LeastSquares>
class IConvection {
// ...
    public:
    using gradient_scheme = GradScheme;
};

And then look for that in your requires clause. Any type that lacks a type alias gradient_scheme doesn't match this template, it isn't a hard error.
template <typename Field>
template <typename Convection>
requires std::derived_from<Convection, scheme::convection::IConvection<typename Convection::gradient_scheme>>
void TransportEquation<Field>::addScheme(Convection&& convection);

